# Windows store app user control event handling

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Assume my windows 8.1 store app consist of a page with a user control and a gridview.
User control has a listview inside.
Now what I want to do is when user change the selected item in the user control's 
listview I want to populate the gridview on the page.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you need more specific help you could post some of the code that you are using. I'd also recommend you look at the MVVM pattern or better define what troubles you are having.

Answer (score 1):

### Use MVVM pattern to establish relationships in your data

You could bind some property of the user control to a portion of your viewmodel which then updates whatever the gridview is bound to as well. I've had some success with using [Prism](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/) but you could just use a simple class for the DataContext and INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

### Bind one control to selected item of another

It is also possible, if you are trying to display details on some sort of complex object, to bind to the SelectedItem of a different control. Such as if you were trying to use a listview as a list of names then display details

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" x:Name="ListOfNames"></ListView>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=ListOfNames}" ></GridView >
```

Comment: Can you explain this in detail by giving a working code example maybe?

Comment: Theres some advice, but it would be helpful to show what you've done so far in the form of an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I haven't done anything yet. My scenario is mentioned above and because of that I'm diffident to use user controls in my app.